# ScaleTransition уменьшение за счёт одной стороны и проблема с текстом

Tags: java, javafx, анимация, transition

Добрый день.

```
public class ButtonAnimation {
  public static void playAnimation(MouseEvent event) {
    Button button = (Button)event.getSource();
    ScaleTransition st = new ScaleTransition(Duration.seconds(0.5), button);

    st.toXProperty().setValue(0.8);
    st.play();
  }
}
```

Здесь button уменьшится, но он будет уменьшаться с 2-х сторон, а я хочу, чтобы он уменьшался только с одной стороны, к примеру с правой. Есть возможность сделать это как-то?

Есть ли также возможность оставить нормальным текст? Просто при уменьшении он сжимается, хотя места остаётся достаточно, чтобы он не изменялся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, я сделал просто 2 анимации: ScaleTransition и TranslateTransition. Что-то такое, только это не уменьшение, а увеличение

```
public static void playAnimation(MouseEvent event) {
    Button button = ((Button) event.getSource());
    ScaleTransition scaleTransition = new ScaleTransition(Duration.seconds(0.5), button);
    TranslateTransition translateTransition = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(0.5), button);

    scaleTransition.toXProperty().setValue(1);
    translateTransition.toXProperty().setValue(0);

    scaleTransition.play();
    translateTransition.play();
}
```

Но не знаю как быть с текстом :(